# Блокировать появление пустого выпадающего списка AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Имеется AutoCompleteTextView с кастомным ArrayAdapter. Допустим, пользователь вводит 2 буквы, появляется список с предложениями, выбирает необходимый и он вставляется в TextView. После этого скрывается клавиатура, а в TextView остаётся пустой огрызок выпадающего списка. Если не остался при скрытии клавы, то появляется при повторном нажатии на TextView. При чём ширина этот пустого списка может быть как во весь размер TextView, так и маленькой. Как можно этого избежать?

Вот так это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ArrayAdapter

```
public class FlavoursArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FlavourModelAdapter> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<FlavourModelAdapter> modelAdapterList;

    public FlavoursArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<FlavourModelAdapter> modelAdapterList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, modelAdapterList);
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.modelAdapterList = new ArrayList<>(modelAdapterList.size());
        this.modelAdapterList.addAll(modelAdapterList);
    }

    private Filter mFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            return ((FlavourModelAdapter) resultValue).getFlavourName();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null) {
                ArrayList<FlavourModelAdapter> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
                for (FlavourModelAdapter modelAdapter : modelAdapterList) {
                    if (modelAdapter.getFlavourName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        suggestions.add(modelAdapter);
                    }
                }
                results.values = suggestions;
                results.count = suggestions.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            clear();
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                addAll((ArrayList<FlavourModelAdapter>) results.values);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tvAdapterItem = view.findViewById(R.id.atvFlavourName);

        FlavourModelAdapter modelAdapter = getItem(position);
        SpannableStringBuilder spannedStr = new SpannableStringBuilder(modelAdapter.getFlavourName());
        String flavourManufacturer = modelAdapter.getFlavourManufacturer();
        if (flavourManufacturer.equals(getContext().getString(R.string.favourites))) {
                spannedStr.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
                        0, 6, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        } else if (flavourManufacturer.equals("some string")) {
            spannedStr.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
                    0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        } else if (flavourManufacturer.equals("some string")) {
            spannedStr.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
                    0, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        } else if (flavourManufacturer.equals("some string")) {
            spannedStr.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
                    0, 11, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }

        if (spannedStr != null) {
            tvAdapterItem.setText(spannedStr);
        } else {
            tvAdapterItem.setText(modelAdapter.getFlavourName());
        }
        return view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }
}
```

R.layout.autocomplete_dropdown_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/atvFlavourName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

AutoCompleteTextView

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/tilFlavourName"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="3"
                                    android:theme="?attr/textInputLayoutHintColor">

                                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/etFlavorName"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:completionThreshold="2"
                                        android:hint="@string/name_tablerow"
                                        android:theme="?attr/aCtVStyle"
                                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                                        android:inputType="text"
                                        android:maxLength="60"
                                        android:popupBackground="?attr/cardBackground"
                                        android:textColor="?attr/textColor"
                                        android:textCursorDrawable="@color/statusbar_color"
                                        android:textSize="15sp"
                                        app:backgroundTint="?attr/editTextUnderLineColor"
                                        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />
                                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**UPD:** Добавил к ACTV OnTouchListener и проверил есть ли в адаптере что-нибудь. Показывает все подходящие к текущему введённому названию элементы.

Потом в  том же OnTouchListener добавил следующее:

```
if (etFlavorName.getAdapter().getCount() > 0){
   etFlavorName.showDropDown();
   }
```

Всё то же самое, только теперь с выбранным из списка и вставленным в ACTV текстом, этот огрызок появляется одновременно с обычным выпадающим списком. Из этого следует, что он вообще не имеет отношения к адаптеру. Чертовщина какая-то.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё наблюдение - в стиле для ACTV через атрибут android:popupBackground можно сделать этот всплывающий фрагмант прозрачным, но остаётся нижнее подчёркивание, за которое отвечает colorControlActivated. Всё бы ничего, но это влияет и на подчёркивание самого ACTV. Незадача.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема как всегда оказалась на поверхности. Это загадочное всплывающее окошко оказалось обычным курсором с кастомным стилем. 
Вот только в какой момент окрашенный курсор стал некорректно отображаться, я так и не понял.

Удалил стиль и всё встало на свои места.

```
  android:theme="?attr/aCtVStyle"

 <item name="aCtVStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewStyleLight</item>

<style name="AutoCompleteTextViewStyleLight" parent="Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownMenuBackgroundLight</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_widget_21_color</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить

```
if (constraint != null) {
```

на

```
if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length != 0) {
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.